# Add ViewModel to View type mapping for intercepted types

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro, ninject-interception

I'm using Caliburn Micro and Ninject together in a WPF app. I'm using `Ninject.Extensions.Interception` to intercept and log calls to my ViewModels, however this is preventing Caliburn to locate the view for ViewModels because Caliburn is being handed the intercepted viewModel (proxy) which is of a different namespace and name.

For instance, instead of getting:

```
MyApp.ViewModels.OrdersViewModel
```

it is getting:

```
Castle.Proxies.IOrdersProxy
```

To complicate things even further, ViewModels and Views are located in different assemblies, so namespace cannot be assumed.

Since I need to interrogate the proxy at runtime I need a way to hook into the View resolution programatically rather than by adding string mappings. I do not see any way to do this - is it possible with Calliburn Micro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got it. Instead of fighting the mappings, I am unwrapping the proxy in the WindowManager instead:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Caliburn.Micro;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;

namespace CAM.Utility
{
    public class WindowManagerEx : WindowManager, IWindowManagerEx
    {
        private readonly List<object> _trayIcons;

        public WindowManagerEx()
        {
            _trayIcons = new List<object>();
        }

        public override bool? ShowDialog(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null)
        {
            rootModel = rootModel.UnwrapProxy();

            return base.ShowDialog(rootModel, context, settings);
        }

        public override void ShowWindow(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null)
        {
            rootModel = rootModel.UnwrapProxy();

            base.ShowWindow(rootModel, context, settings);
        }

        public override void ShowPopup(object rootModel, object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null)
        {
            rootModel = rootModel.UnwrapProxy();

            base.ShowPopup(rootModel, context, settings);
        }

        public bool? ShowDialog<TViewModel>(object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null)
        {
            var viewModelInstance = IoC.Get<TViewModel>();

            return ShowDialog(viewModelInstance, context, settings);
        }

        public void ShowWindow<TViewModel>(object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null)
        {
            var viewModelInstance = IoC.Get<TViewModel>();

            ShowWindow(viewModelInstance, context, settings);
        }

        public void ShowPopup<TViewModel>(object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null)
        {
            var viewModelInstance = IoC.Get<TViewModel>();

            ShowPopup(viewModelInstance, context, settings);
        }

        public void ShowTrayIcon<TViewModel>(object context = null)
        {
            var viewModelInstance = IoC.Get<TViewModel>();

            _trayIcons.Add(viewModelInstance);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            foreach (var trayIcon in _trayIcons)
            {
                var disposable = trayIcon as IDisposable;
                if (disposable != null)
                {
                    disposable.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class CastleProxyExtensions
    {
        public static object UnwrapProxy(this object target)
        {
            var proxy = target as IProxyTargetAccessor;

            if (proxy != null)
            {
                dynamic dynamicProxy = proxy;

                dynamic interceptors = dynamicProxy.__interceptors;

                dynamic interceptor = interceptors[0];

                target = interceptor.Instance;
            }

            return target;
        }
    }
}
```

Also in case you are wondering what IWindowManagerEx is:

```
public interface IWindowManagerEx : IWindowManager, IDisposable
{
    bool? ShowDialog<TViewModel>(object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);

    void ShowWindow<TViewModel>(object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);

    void ShowPopup<TViewModel>(object context = null, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);

    void ShowTrayIcon<TViewModel>(object context = null);
}
```